# How do I get the current total cost for Google Cloud Platform programmatically so I can optimize costs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

The Google Cloud Platform billing interface (at `https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/<account_number>/reports?project=<project_name>&organizationId=<org_id>`) that you get when you click on billing in the Cloud Console has a table with the current month-to-date cost -- the column labeled subtotal in the image whose value I scratched out in blue.
[image: Screenshot of Google cloud billing]

I would like to get that value (or the aggregate cost for a project over some other period) using the [RPC API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rpc/) (or other appropriate programmatic method). The keywords subtotal and total don't seem to come up anywhere in the API.

I want to use this for benchmarking. I want to run version X of my code with a certain configuration and load and see how much it cost by looking at the total cost before and after the run. Then I can compare configurations and versions and see the effects of various optimizations.

I did some basic Google searches and checked StackOverflow, but the closest I got were [this answer to a question about programmatic costs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41041999/309334) and [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263225/309334), but they do not help because the export happens every day and I'd like to check the change in an interval of a few minutes.

In the worst-case scenario, I can scrape the billing web page. But I'm hoping there's a better way since scraping is usually brittle (and Google might not like it).